# Variables only printable from foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach, global-variables

I want to get the variables within a foreach loop in PHP, when it is within the while loop I can print all the object data but when I echo the variables outside of the while loop it prints only a value of the variable, how do I declare the variables global and access their values anywhere?

```
<?php
              global $answerList, $countList;
              foreach( $finalAnswer as $answerID ) {
                foreach ($answers as $ans => $answer_list) {
                  foreach ($answer_list->unique('AnswerShortID') as $answer) {
                    if ($answer->AnswerShortID === $answerID){
                        $answerList = $answer->Text;
                        $countList = $answer_list->count();
                        echo $answerList;
                    }
                  }
                }
              } 
              echo $answerList;
              
              ?>
```

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `global`, you are overwriting the variables each time through the loop so the variable only contains the last one.  Just save to an array, then you can loop it later or `implode` it to display:

```
              // you don't need to do this in the loop
              $countList = $answer_list->count();

              foreach ($answer_list->unique('AnswerShortID') as $answer) {
                if ($answer->AnswerShortID === $answerID){
                    $answerList[] = $answer->Text;
                }
              }

              echo implode(',', $answerList);
              //or
              foreach($answerList as $value) {
                  echo "<something>$value</something>other stuff";
              }
```

Answer (score 1):

The below will store all values in a string, which you can then echo out later. By adding a period before the equals sign you are adding new values to the end of the string with each iteration of the loop. Your code currently deletes the last value and replaces it with a new one every time you complete the loop.

```
<?php
          global $answerList, $countList;
          foreach( $finalAnswer as $answerID ) {
            foreach ($answers as $ans => $answer_list) {
              foreach ($answer_list->unique('AnswerShortID') as $answer) {
                if ($answer->AnswerShortID === $answerID){
                    $answerList .= $answer->Text;
                    $countList .= $answer_list->count();
                    echo $answerList;
                }
              }
            }
          } 
          echo $answerList;
          
          ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for oyur quick response. What I want is to access the 2 variables from outside of the while loop with the values they've been populated with within the while loop. The code is not ina function just declared within the PHP tag

Comment: Have you tried using an array instead?  Every time the loop runs it will overwrite the last value, meaning that you will only get the last value set.  If you don't want to use an array, you could create a string by adding a period before the equals sign to concatenate it: $answerList .= $answer->Text;

Comment: How do I, please help me with the snippet. Thanks

Comment: I've just updated my answer. Does that work?

Comment: Thanks, just a moment, please. BRB.

Comment: You are a genius!